# Joomla URL The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, joomla, file-not-found

When clicking on any links in the administrator dashboard of Joomla I am getting the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache Server at site-url Port 80

example path that I am trying to access: /administrator/index.php?option=com_sections&scope=content

I am still however able to access the dashboard by logging in. Just clicking on any admin links yields this error. The clients site still works so this tells me that it isn't an issue with the database.

I have tried restoring to a recent backup but have been unsuccessful in my endeavors.

Comment: Have you touched anything on the backend?  If it was working before and doesn't now - what changed?  What did you do last before this happened?

Comment: Nothing on the backend has been changed prior to this. The only access our client has to this is the actual dashboard to make updates.

Comment: It was working prior to now though, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I ultimately did a backup that reflected how the site looked a week ago. I don't know what happened within the week but it had to be a change with the configuration file. I'll be going over and comparing everything.

Comment: Ensure to use the correct subdomain. `www.example.com` is not `example.com`.

Comment: did you edit an .htaccess? install an administrator plugin?

Comment: Something had to have been changed or been added at some point, somewhere.  Those things don't change on their own and it doesn't go from working to not working without being hacked or having something change.  Are you 100% sure the other guy didn't do something?  I've seen that happen more times than I care to think about!